# Implementing 3D Secure verification in Custom API based payment method in magento

Tags: magento, payment-gateway

I am working on custom API based payment gateway. For 3D secure verification payment gateway return encoded form that need to submit to redirect user on third party site for card verification.

I am working on this code in capture function of payment model.

Here My question is How can I use encoded form to redirect user from payment model capture method to third party site.

I have used getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl to redirect user in Hosted form Method.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a new controller action and redirected users to it from getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl().  This new controller action will show a hidden form that displays the MD, PaReq etc as hidden fields.  This form can then auto submit to the ACS URL.

Some untested pseudo-code is below.  You'll need to modify it according to your needs but hopefully it gets the idea across.

Inside your payment method instance:

```
function getOrderPlaceUrl() {
    Mage::getModel('core/session')->setMd('valuehere'); //  Set all the 3DS params into the session by the time this function call finished.  Don't set them here in actual code - bad style.  This is just for demonstration.
    return Mage::getUrl('module/payment/action');
}
```

app/code/local/Namespace/Module/controllers/Payment.php:

```
class Namespace_Module_PaymentController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front {
    public function redirectAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

app/design/frontent/base/default/layout/module.xml:

```
<namespace_module_payment_redirect>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="namespace_module/payment_redirect</block" name="namespace.module.payment.redirect" template="namespace/module/payment/redirect.tpl" />
    </reference>
</namespace_module_payment_redirect>
```

app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Block/Payment/Redirect.php:

```
class Namespace_Module_Block_Payment_Redirect extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
    public function getMd() {
        return Mage::getModel('core/session')->getMd();
    }
}
```

app/design/frontend/base/default/templates/module/payment/redirect.tpl:

```
<form action="payment_gateway_url_here" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="MD" value="<?php print $this->getMd(); ?>" />
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am checking all my conditions in Capture function after that redirect on controller but when redirect order status already changed to processing and generate invoice. .. Can you please help is I ma doing anything wrong

Comment: @PankajPareek The code above won't take you all the way; you'll need to extend it.  By the time you redirect to the custom controller Magento has already called `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment::place()`.  This function is responsible for calling your payment method's `authorize()` and `capture()` functions.  You should look at extending `authorize()` and `capture()` as you require.  My own solution also involved attaching an observer to event `checkout_submit_all_after` which loaded the active order and updated its state and status to something like 'Pending 3D Secure'.

Comment: How Can I control to generate invoice in capture method ?

Comment: @PankajPareek You might want to create a new SO question :)

Comment: @PankajPareek And if this answered your original question feel free to accept the answer!